# Memoization of Fibonacci using generic Int => Int helper

Tags: scala, fibonacci-sequence, meta-programming, memoization

I'm trying to understand memoization using Scala. I took the Fibonacci sequence as an example because of the high cost of recursively computing numbers in the sequence without memoization.

```
class memoize private (val f: Int => Int) {
  import scala.collection.mutable
  val cache = new mutable.HashMap[Int, Int]()
  def memoized_f(x : Int) : Int =
    cache.getOrElseUpdate(x, f(x))
}
object memoize {
  def apply(f: Int => Int) : Int => Int = new memoize(f).memoized_f
}

val fib : Int=>Int = memoize((n:Int) => {
  if (n <= 1) n else fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
})
```

With memoization the function `fib` is called 10 times compared to 276 without it. I discovered that `val fib` is required: `def fib` results in the memo object being created on each call to `fib`!

I realize that this could eventually be generalized by parameterising `memoize` with a type `T` (or key `K` and value `V`) to replace `Int`. But I wanted to start somewhere simple to understand how the technique works. Given that I'm looking at memoizing only `Int => Int` functions, could what I've done be improved in terms of function or style?

I've also discovered a couple of related items on the web: [Is there a generic way to memoize in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16257378/is-there-a-generic-way-to-memoize-in-scala) and [Memo in ScalaZ](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/scalaz-seven/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Memo.scala) (see also [this tutorial](http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz-day16)), but I'm not entirely sure how what I've done relates to them.

Answer (score 4):

For generic memoization I pretty much always use scalaz `Memo` but when I compute sequences, I personally prefer using the standard Scala `Stream`.

`Stream` naturally memoize every computed value. Your solution could be refactored as:

```
lazy val fib = {
  def f(a: Int, b: Int): Stream[Int] = a #:: f(b, a + b)
  f(0, 1)
}

scala> fib.take(10) foreach println
0
1
1
2
3
5
8
13
21
34

scala> fib(45)
res1: Int = 1134903170
```